# Generate list of payment addresses using CardanoCLI-JS

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli

I am trying to generate a list of (unused) payment addresses with CardanoCLI-JS, but how to do it?

```
    const wallet = cardanocliJs.wallet("Main");
    const address = cardanocliJs.addressBuild("Main", {
      paymentVkey: wallet.payment.vkey,
      stakeVkey: wallet.stake.vkey,
    });

console.log(address);
```

This outputs the location of the vkey, which gets updated on execution, but contains the same address as before?

Is this something CardanoCLI-JS just can't do right now?

Cardano-Wallet-JS has `wallet.getAddresses()`, which returns an array of 20 addresses, but I'd really like to stick to one JS library...

(Can someone pls create the tags cardanocli-js and cardano-wallet-js? thanks...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardano-cli (what the JS library wraps) has no notion of what a wallet is, how to derive addresses from mnemonic/public key, etc... cardano-wallet-js wraps the cardano-wallet process and can get information about a wallet and it's state on the network (which is required if you want to know unused addresses as a process needs to scrape entire chain to see if an address has been used or not). If you're looking for a simple library to derive addresses and don't care about state, there's a GHCJS build of cardano-addresses https://www.npmjs.com/package/cardano-addresses which provides the ability to derive addresses from a root key, account public key or your 24 word mnemonic for the wallet. However; to identify if an address was used or not, you would need a db-sync or explorer API (like graphql, blockfrost, rosetta, etc...) to check the state of the chain for that particular address.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up... kinda confusing if you ask me. Why not work on ONE JS Library which can do it all?

Comment: Mainly because running js code is slow.